# C# User input needs to be >= 2, but how to make it so?

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, int

This part is hard for me for some reason.  Everything else works nicely, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it to where it re-asks the question if the input is >=2...

```
if (minimumSides >= 2)
```

I get this part, but it hates `minimumsides >= 2.`

```
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter minimum number of sides >2: ");
    int.TryParse(inputminside, out minimumSides);                               
    if (minimumSides >= 2)
        Console.Write("Enter minimum number of sides >2: ");
    else
        inputminside = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (!int.TryParse(inputminside, out minimumSides));
```

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast...I'll start testing and report back later...cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
do {
    Console.Write("Enter minimum number of sides >2: ");
    inputminside = Console.ReadLine();
} while (!int.TryParse(inputminside, out minimumSides) || minimumSides < 2);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&&` in place of `||`? If user enters string, it won't hold valid.

Comment: This worked perfectlty!  I was only missing || minimumSides < 2 in my code =/  Thanks again! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be that during the first iteration of the loop "inputminside" has not been initialized?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it:

```
var minimumSides  = 0;

while (minimumSides <=2)
{
    Console.Write("Enter minimum number of sides >2: ");
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out minimumSides);
}

// carry on with your code here...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want -

```
do
{
   Console.Write("Enter minimum number of sides >2: ");
   inputminside = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (!int.TryParse(inputminside, out minimumSides) && minimumSides < 2);
```